# Improving cache performance while iterating through a simple 2D array?

Tags: java, c, caching

I have been trying to think of a way to rewrite the code below to improve cache performance ( by reducing misses in cache) in the array.

I am aware that the array is stored in memory row by row (sequentially), so ary[0][0], ary[0][1], ary[0][2],....ary[1][0], ary[1][1], ary[1][2]... ary[50][0], ary[50][1]...ary[50][50]. However, I am uncertain how to use this info to help me figure out how to modify the loop to improve cache performance.

```
for (c = 0; c < 50; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < 50; d++)
        ary[d][c] = ary[d][c] + 1;
```

Comment: Think about the order in which memory elements are accessed with your current code. Think about what you might do with your code to keep each access close in memory to the one before.

Comment: Either C or java will work. I am more concerned with the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access all the cells of a row at once, just inverse the two loops:

```
for (d = 0; d < 50; d++)
    for (c = 0; c < 50; c++)
        ary[d][c] = ary[d][c] + 1;
```

Or even

```
for (d = 0; d < 50; d++)
    int[] array = ary[d];
    for (c = 0; c < 50; c++)
        array[c] = array[c] + 1;
```

But I doubt it has any significant impact, or even any impact at all, especially on a so tiny array. Make your code simple and readable. Don't pre-optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain how this will improve cache performance??

Comment: You explained it yourself in your question. The inner loop loops over a single int array rather than looping among 50 different int arrays. like your original code.

Comment: arr[d][c+1] is very likely to reside in the same cache line as arr[d][c].  Also, the hardware prefetcher will do the right thing if you do a bunch of sequential memory accesses.

Answer (score 3):

Swap the loop order.  You're accessing `arr[1][0]` right after `arr[0][0]`. `arr[1][0]` is much farther away, while `arr[0][1]` is at the next address.

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize the number of cache misses to improve performance. Each cache miss results in memory access and loading of a new block to the cache. This block contains not just the value you need but also additional adjacent values from the memory. You need to make use of the locality principle, i.e. use as much values from each memory access as you can. Like you mentioned in your observation, the array is stored row by row in the memory, so traversing the array in sequential manner will minimize the number of cache misses. Getting back to your code,
either swap the loop order:

```
for (d = 0; d < 50; d++)
    for (c = 0; c < 50; c++)
        ary[d][c] = ary[d][c] + 1;
```

or swap  the indices in the calculation:

```
for (c = 0; c < 50; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < 50; d++)
        ary[c][d] = ary[c][d] + 1;
```

You can even treat the 2D array as a 1D array of 50*50 size and just use a single for loop to scan it from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to do anything, other than swapping the loop, because caches are designed to exploit the locality of reference in code on its own, which means it will cache the first element along with the few following elements (spacial locality) from the array and will keep them in cache for a while (temporal locality).

However, some compilers let you control caching, for example gcc has the  [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)  which lets you control which data should be prefetched and whether it should be left in cache or not.

> — Built-in Function: void __builtin_prefetch (const void *addr, rw, locality)
>
> This function is used to minimize cache-miss latency by moving data into a cache before it is accessed. You can insert calls to
>   __builtin_prefetch into code for which you know addresses of data in memory that is likely to be accessed soon. If the target supports
>   them, data prefetch instructions are generated. If the prefetch is
>   done early enough before the access then the data will be in the cache
>   by the time it is accessed.

And the manual gives this example:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  __builtin_prefetch (&a[i+j], 1, 1);
  __builtin_prefetch (&b[i+j], 0, 1);
  /* ... */
}
```